# Django: Uploading Avatar Imagefile to media-Folder of Custom User Profile is not working

Tags: django, django-models, avatar

I'm currently trying to create a Custom User Model for being able to add a Avatar-Imagefield to ever User.

Therefore I've created a Model **Profile** with avatars as the directory *(media/avatars/)* for all Images:

```
class Profile(models.Model):

user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
avatar = models.ImageField('Avatar', upload_to="avatars", default="avatars/profil_picture_icon.png")
```

I created the needed classes **ProfileInline** and **UserAdmin**:

```
class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
model = Profile
can_delete = False

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
inlines = (ProfileInline,)

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

I also defined the **media-directory** inside the settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

After that, I created a Form **ProfileForm**, where the User can upload the Image and a **postsavereceiver** to create a basic Profile-Model every time I'm creating a new User:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = models.Profile
    exclude = ('user',)


def post_save_receiver(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
if created:
    user_profile = models.Profile(user=instance)
    user_profile.save()

post_save.connect(post_save_receiver, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

Inside my Template I then created a form with the Avatar-ImageField and a Save-Button to Upload that Image:

```
     <form action="/profil/" method="post" id="avatar_form">
    {% csrf_token %}

     <img style="border-radius: 100px" id= "Profil_Image" src=" {{ user.profile.avatar.url }}">
        {% load widget_tweaks %}
        {{ profile_form.avatar|add_class:"profile_form" }}

     <button id="update_button" style="left: 1210px; top: 385px" type="submit" form="avatar_form" name="avatar_update_btn" value="">Speichern</button>

 </form>
```

Lastly inside my **views.py** the User can Update the Default-Image

```
        elif 'avatar_update_btn' in request.POST:
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        models.Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user).update(avatar="avatars/" + profile_form.data['avatar'])
```

**-> And here we got the Problem.**

It's updating the Avatar-URL inside the Database with the correct Filename, but it can't find the Image after reloading the Page because the Image was not uploaded into the media/avatars/-Folder and I have no idea why.

As soon as I'm saving the Image over the admin-Page it's working perfectly and a new Image-Instance is created inside the avatars-Folder. But as soon as I'm trying to upload it with the ImageField, it's not creating a new Instance of the Image inside the Folder.

I think it must have something to do with the "update" - function of the model. Maybe with "update" it's just changing the URL without creating a new Image-Instance, that's why I've tried to upload it with the profile_form.save() - function. But it won't let me save it, since the save()-function wants to create a new Model-Instance but the Profile-Model is already existing.

Can you help me out here?

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is with your settings.py.  `BASE_DIR` is obviously the base directory of your project, where `manage.py` is located.  Thus, your media folder should be in that directory, otherwise Django won't find it.  And I take it you have a folder called `avatar` within the media folder.  Try:

```py
    import os

    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) # You probably already have this
    print(BASE_DIR) # Do this to check if your BASE_DIR is correct
    ...

    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: thank you for answering! :) I just figured it out. I just deleted the whole Profile-Instance inside the Database with models.Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user).delete() and created a new one. Then it saved the image inside the folder.. finally.